# 500 Error on a perl page

Tags: perl

I have a perl page that I'm trying to first get working on a local host environment before I move it over to my production server.  However if I use a simple `hello.pl` page it works perfect in the browser:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "Hello this is just a kindness.\n";
```

However when I try to load the actual script 'step1.pl' and open it I just get a 500 error.  So I tailed the error_log to see why and I found this.

```
 Mon Aug 11 08:19:07 2014] [error] Can't locate CGI.pm in @INC (@INC contains: 
/usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl 
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 . /etc/httpd) at 
/var/www/vhosts/ibstrategies.com/httpdocs/step1.pl line 3.\nBEGIN failed--compilation 
aborted at /var/www/vhosts/ibstrategies.com/httpdocs/step1.pl line 3.\n
```

However I know that CGI.pm is installed.

`[root@chelsea /]# perl -e 'use CGI; print $CGI::VERSION."\n";' 4.03`

Any ideas?

Comment: **Where** is CGI.pm installed? It doesn't appear to be in the path listed by the error message.

Comment: Well is there a better way to do check than this because this doesn't find anything 
<code> 
[root@chelsea /]# perl -MList::Util -e'print $INC{"List/CGI.pm"} . "\n"' </code>

Comment: You can see CGI.pm from the CLI ($PATH) but not from your webserver (@INC) you need to do 'locate CGI.pm' and add the the path to @INC

Comment: This was cross posted here already: http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=1096986

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the Perl binary that used when you run `perl` from the command line? Type `which perl` to find out.

Is there a shebang line at the top of step1.pl? I bet that points to a different version of Perl.

But CGI.pm has been included with the standard Perl distribution for over fifteen years. If you have a version of Perl that doesn't include it, then your Perl is either ridiculously old or bizarrely crippled. In either of those cases, I'd strongly advise moving to a server with a better version of Perl installed.